# How to calculate auc_score and f_score?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, auc

I want to calculate and print auc_score, f_score and others metrics using scickit learn in python?
I am doing NLP, in the beginning my set are list of words, i vectorize them to do some prediction.
My y_predi are true or false, i need to transform them into values (0 and 1)

My code :

```
    #Vectorization
        x_test_vect = pipe_vect.transform(x_test)

        #Create predictive set
        y_pred = model.predict_proba(x_test_vect)

     #Calculate treshold
        fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, y_pred[:, 1])
        spr =  np.array(tpr) + (1 - np.array(fpr))
        threshold = thresholds[np.argmax(spr)]
        y_predi = [y >= threshold for y in y_pred[:, 1]]

    #Calculate AUC score
        AUC = roc_auc_score(y_test, y_predi[:, 1])
```

My print :

```
y_pred [[0.89882979 0.10117021]
 [0.87       0.13      ]
 [0.65       0.35      ]
 [0.94122287 0.05877713]
 [0.50868421 0.49131579]
 [0.97847458 0.02152542]
 [0.99       0.01      ]
 [0.21       0.79      ]
 [0.94       0.06      ]
 [0.94604348 0.05395652]]
y_test [1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0]
y_predi [False, False, True, False, True, False, False, True, False, False]
threshold 0.2407608695652174
```

the error :

```
AUC = roc_auc_score(y_test, y_predi[:, 1])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Comment: Please do not use ad hoc abbreviations like "*calcul*" (edited). Also, code that comes *after* the error is irrelevant (never executed) and should not be included here (edited out).

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to slice the y_predi wrongly. From the print it's a 1-d array and you can give it directly.
When you try to do y_predi[:,1], it tries to give the first column for all the rows, but your array is 1-d and there is no 1st column, hence the error.